# Force DataGridView CheckBox to be Checked Under Certian Conditions

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, checkbox

All, what I want to do is simple (or so I thought). I currently have a `DataGridView` with checkboxes to indicate whether user should process or not. Some processes rely on others so I force the reliant processes checked using

```
private void dataGridViewProcess_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == (int)ProcessColumns.Error)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridViewProcess.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                                  .Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()))
        {
            Utils.ErrMsg(String.Format("{0}", 
                (String.IsNullOrEmpty(siteReportArr[currentSite, e.RowIndex]) ?
                "Error message currently unavalible. Try again later." : 
                siteReportArr[currentSite, e.RowIndex])));
        }
    }
    dataGridViewProcess.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}

private void dataGridViewProcess_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (!bInLoadEvent && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == (int)CurrentProcess.N)
        {
            DataGridViewRow rowA = dataGridViewProcess.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            DataGridViewRow rowB = dataGridViewProcess.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1];
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(rowA.Cells[(int)ProcessColumns.Process].Value) 
                == false)
            {    
                rowB.Cells[(int)ProcessColumns.Process].Value = false;
            }
        }
        ...
        else if (e.RowIndex == (int)CurrentProcess.C)
        {
            DataGridViewRow rowB = dataGridViewProcess.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            DataGridViewRow rowA = dataGridViewProcess.Rows[e.RowIndex - 1];
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(rowA.Cells[(int)ProcessColumns.Process].Value) 
                == true)
            {
                rowB.Cells[(int)ProcessColumns.Process].Value = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All of these programatic changes work fine bar one, the last one shown in the `dataGridViewProcess_CellValueChanged` event. Here, if the process before `C` is checked and the user tries to uncheck `C`, I want to force it to remain checked. I currently can't get it to do this.

I have tried using the `DataGridView` `Validated` event, and using `CellDirtyStateChanged` event to no avail. Any help with this (seemingly very basic) problem would be most appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is where you are in the chain of event processing. I copied your code and modified it a bit. The key is that the last condition is the (probably) the only one where you are modifying the cell currently being edited. I found that the code executes as expected, but the checkbox doesn't change - until the checkbox loses focus, in which case is changes to the correct value. I got it to work by changing the following line in `dataGridViewProcess_CellContentClick` from

```
dataGridViewProcess.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

to

```
dataGridViewProcess.EndEdit();
```

You will note on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.commitedit.aspx) that CommitEdit does not end the actual edit.

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for your help here, it is much appreciated. I am well under it today, thanks again for your time...